# Using HIDAPI, how can you raw data question

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, hid, hidapi

I'm using Trustmaster products.

I'm going to bring raw data.
I'm going to bring up the data on the throttle.

Trustmaster's product doc says that the data on the throttle comes from 14 bits and 16383 data.

However, if you use the library to retrieve the data, it's 0-255.
Divide it 14 times and come out.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

The data output method we want is 0 to 16383.

Comment: Use what library? What is the code you're using?

Comment: I used https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.